# How to definitively set UITabBar background color and tint color

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have been trying to set my `UITabBar`'s tint color and background color for quite some time now and nothing seems to work. 
So far I have tried:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

as well as:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

Neither of these seemed to have any effect on my tab bar. I'd also like to mention that I have the VC embedded in a navigation controller for which the global tint color that I set works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want to set tabbar's `tint and barTint color` implicitly then in your `Appdelegate.swift`,

```
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .orange
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

If you want to set tabbar's `tint and barTint color` for specific viewController then in `ViewController.swift`,

```
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .orange
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = .green
```

Comment: Hi @Lion, barTintColor is not exist in this `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor`?

Comment: @Khuong I'm able to get to it by accessing the instance, but I'm unable to do so via the class with `appearance()`

Comment: @Khuong It is there, it's just that Xcode completely refuses to show it in the autocomplete options

Comment: swift 4:  
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green

Comment: `UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green` seems to do absolutely nothing. barTint gets it close but definitely not the same. Is this expected?

Comment: yes! It is expected! You can set background image of your tabbar to achieve exact color you want! @DaniSpringer

Comment: So I have to create an image of the color I want? And the moment I want to change it, instead of updating a six character hex string, I need to make a new image? This is the best way?

Answer (score 22):

Set tab bar background color **with barTintColor**:

```
self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
//or
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

And for tab bar tint color:

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // Selected tab color
//or
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

[image]

Comment: my tabBar is look like this But when user tap any tabs the item will disable But the color will change too how can I change that?here is my question link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45439032?noredirect=1

Comment: Color gets close but not same. Try making the view background the same color and see for yourself

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between `tintColor` and `barTintColor`. Is it possible to dream up any more obscure and unhelpful property names, Apple?

Answer (score 2):

In similar fashion to how UINavigationBar is by default transparent on iOS 15 when there is no content behind it, the UITabBar works the same way. This might either be a nice visual refresh you get for free (since it is turned on by default once you build with Xcode 13) or it might cause a lot of issues for your app.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { 
    let tabBarAppearance: UITabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance() 
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground() 
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.tabBarBackground 
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance 
}
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) { 
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance 
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that actually got the expected result for ios 15+

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set it from UIEditor like so

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always like to do some kinds of settings on the storyboard. Here is the `@IBDesignable`  extension

```
@IBDesignable extension UITabBar {
@IBInspectable var barTintColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = uiColor
    }
    get {
        guard let color = UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor else { return nil }
        return color
    }
}}
```

Answer (score -3):

**Swift 4+ version**

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: This answer is copy of above https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626577/11077258 this one