# how to change disabled item color in TabBar in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor, uitabbaritem

I have a TabBar in my project and when user select item this item will disable but the color will change too! I want the color is same as other items color in TabBar 
I used

```
item.isEnabled = false
```

for disable item but this codes here won't work for this item

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 126/255, green: 0/255, blue: 64/255, alpha: 1.0)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

}
```

Comment: If you want to change the color of the selected item then give that color as  UITabBar.appearance().tintColor

Comment: no you didn't understand what I want - when user tap one of the item it will be disable but the color of that will change too I want the color doesn't change even when item is disable - remember that the item is disable not deselected

Comment: Yup I meant that only the disabled item is the item which the user selects right ?

Comment: yes when user select item it will be disable But I don't want to change the color I want disable item color is similar to the enable items do we have in swift ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have the same problem:-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code -

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.gray
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.gray
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no because the item is selected not unselect but its disable

Comment: This solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the UITabBarControllerDelegate method in order to disable the selection

```
try this code 

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return false
    }
```