# How to change the background color of UITabBar controller having 7 items?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have changed the bar tint colour of `TabBar`. I want to change the background of an item which is white.

Comment: please add more detail

Answer (score 0):

Please be more descriptive.

If you want to change background of bar items you can access them by `tabBar.items`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set tabbar's tint and barTint color implicitly then in your `Appdelegate.swift`,

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

If you want to set tabbar's tint and barTint color for specific `viewController` then in `ViewController.swift`,

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626377/how-to-definitiveley-set-uitabbar-background-color-and-uitabbar-tint-color)

Comment: It's better to out this link as comment instead of copy & paste code.