# How do I get the UITabController to show above the tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Below is my Swift code to display a tab bar controller using UITabController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 200, height: 52))
        button.setTitle("Log in", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        button.center = view.center
    }

    @objc func didTapButton(){
        let tabBarVC = UITabBarController()
        
        let vc1 = FirstViewController()
        let vc2 = SecondViewController()
        let vc3 = ThirdViewController()
        let vc4 = FourthViewController()
        let vc5 = FifthViewController()
        
        vc1.title = "Home"
       
        
        tabBarVC.setViewControllers([vc1], animated: false)
        tabBarVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(tabBarVC, animated: true)
    }
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func  viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        title = "Home"
    }
}
```

I have omitted the code for other controllers to reduce verbosity

I got this code from a youtube video from an older version of xcode, below are the images of my result and the one I am expecting:

Result:

[image]

Expectation:

[image]

How do I get the window to end above the tab bar?

Comment: Have you tried to set a background color to the tab bar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626377/how-to-definitively-set-uitabbar-background-color-and-tint-color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set appearance to your tab bar like this:

```
let tabBarVC = UITabBarController()
    
// Update based on your font requirements
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
    
tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    
/* Note: To reset background and shadow properties to display opaque colors can use - tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground() */
tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
    
tabBarVC.tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tabBarVC.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
}
```

And your full function will look like:

```
@objc func didTapButton(){
    
    let tabBarVC = UITabBarController()
    
    // Update based on your font requirements
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
    
    tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
    tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    
    /* Note: To reset background and shadow properties to display opaque colors can use - tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground() */
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
    
    tabBarVC.tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        tabBarVC.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    }
    
    let vc1 = FirstViewController()
    let vc2 = SecondViewController()
    let vc3 = ThirdViewController()
    let vc4 = FourthViewController()
    let vc5 = FifthViewController()
    
    vc1.title = "Home"
    vc2.title = "Items"
    vc3.title = "Orders"
    vc4.title = "Analytics"
    vc5.title = "Account"
    
    tabBarVC.setViewControllers([vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5], animated: false)
    tabBarVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(tabBarVC, animated: true)
}
```

And result will be:

[image]